# Attempted to load ad before SDK initialization in Applovin to load the AppOpen ads on cold start in Android (Background to Foreground is working fine)

Tags: android, kotlin, ads, applovin

Unable to show the AppOpen on the initial launch or cold start. i am getting the error as Attempted to load ad before SDK initialization. Please wait until after the SDK has initialized,

I have initialized the Applovin SDK in the Application, so it show the AppOpen on the every screens. But when I am launching initially it shows Attempted to load ad before SDK.

Background to foreground is working fine without any errors.

Initialized the AppOpen globaly in the app. Still failed to load the Ad on cold launch and shows the Attempt to load ad before SDK initialized

```
        AppLovinSdk.getInstance( applicationContext ).setMediationProvider( "max" );
        AppLovinSdk.getInstance(this).initializeSdk()

        val sdk = AppLovinSdk.getInstance(this)
        sdk.settings.isMuted = true // to mute
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            sdk.showMediationDebugger()
            AppLovinSdk.getInstance(this).settings.setVerboseLogging(true)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the callback to know whether the SDK is fully initialized or not,

```
class MainActivity : Activity()
{
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        // Make sure to set the mediation provider value to "max" to ensure proper functionality
        AppLovinSdk.getInstance( context ).setMediationProvider( "max" )
        AppLovinSdk.getInstance( context ).initializeSdk({ configuration: AppLovinSdkConfiguration ->
            // AppLovin SDK is initialized, start loading ads
        })
    }
}
```

Once the SDK is fully initialized you can load the ad on starup.

Comment: Same issue now as well

Comment: did you try putting the show ad code in the `initializeSdk` block?

Comment: yes did that.Still issue